# Apply 'query' to json.field while using ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, pug

for

```
$scope.phones = [ 

    {"name": "Nexus S",
 "snippet": "Fast just got faster with Nexus S."},
{"name": "Motorola XOOM™ with Wi-Fi",
 "snippet": "The Next, Next Generation tablet."},
{"name": "MOTOROLA XOOM™",
 "snippet": "The Next, Next Generation tablet."}

];
```

The html (jade)

```
p Search <input ng-model="query">
```

The below applies the 'filter| query' to the whole of 'phone'. How do you apply the query only to a field in phone?

like (phones.snippet| filter: query)

```
li(ng-repeat="phone in phones|filter:query")
```

Comment: What do you mean by applying query to a field?

Comment: in the above. if i type 'nex' all three set of values will be selected because, 'nex' is present in name/snippet field of 'phones'. I want to select only a value if 'nex' is present only in the 'name' field, not any other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define the filter yourself:

```
function MainController($scope) {
$scope.searchparam = "Nexus";

$scope.query = function(item) {
    return item.name.contains($scope.searchparam);
};
$scope.phones = 
    [ 
        {"name": "Nexus S", "snippet": "Fast just got faster with Nexus S."},
        {"name": "Motorola XOOM™ with Wi-Fi", "snippet": "The Next, Next Generation tablet."},
        {"name": "MOTOROLA XOOM™", "snippet": "The Next, Next Generation tablet."}
    ];}
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/FAJDk/47/)

Comment: how does the query execute? i have to call the function? can it auto execute on change of input field, somehow?

Comment: its actually reflecting an input box. there is no response on input

Comment: write "Motorola" uppercased, then write "MOTOROLA" all capped

Comment: There is just a input box. The rest of the screen does not reflect any changes on input. it remains blank.